# Ion temperature in plasmas

Tags: collision, plasma-physics

Normally ions are considered to be at different temperature than other species  in plasmas. My question is : How does ion-neutral collision  effect ion temperature in a plasma ?

Comment: My main question is, how does ion-neutral collision effect ion temperature in a plasma ?

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143738/59023 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460461/59023

Comment: Usually, neutrals got ionized in the plasma. However neutral beams are used to heat the plasma in Tokamaks. If the interaction time is large electron energy is transferred into the ions. The heat capacity of electrons is much less compared to ions, hence ions can not reach a very high temperature.

Comment: If the ion-neutral collision is less, will the ions have a higher temperature than when ion-neutral collision is higher ? Let's assume the neutrals are at room temperature.