# What is meant by "collective behavior" in the definition of plasma?

Tags: terminology, plasma-physics

> "Plasmas are many-body systems, with enough mobile charged particles to cause some collective behavior ." [M.S. Murillo and J.C.Weisheit Physics Reports 302, 1-65 (1998)].

In the above definition what is meant by "collective behavior" ?

Comment: magnetic fields are a result of collective behavior of charged particles. https://phys.org/news/2018-11-magnetic-fields-deep-space-wiggle.html , also fluid like behavior in general

Comment: anna v thank you for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plasmas are controlled by long-range interactions (i.e., [Coulomb potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy) and magnetic fields) and so the particles respond accordingly.  Since electric fields do work to get rid of themselves, a [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) will reach what is called a quasi-neutral state, i.e., equal number densities of oppositely charged particles or:
$$
\sum_{s} \ Z_{s} \ n_{s} = 0
$$
where $Z_{s}$ is the charge state of species $s$ and $n_{s}$ is the number density of species $s$.

This can manifest in a fluid-like behavior and the amount which the fluid-like behavior dominates depends upon the plasma parameters like number density, magnetic field, or plasma $\beta$ given by:
$$
\beta = \tfrac{ 2 \ \mu_{o} \ n_{o} \ k_{B} \ T }{ B_{o}^{2} }
$$
where $n_{o}$ is the total number density, $T$ is the total temperature (see definition at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/375611/59023), and $B_{o}$ is the magnetic field magnitude.

Highly collisional plasmas, e.g., [solar photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere), also behave like fluids as they are collisionally mediated.  That is, the relevant frequencies like the [cyclotron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron_resonance), $\Omega_{cs}$, and [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation), $\omega_{ps}$, frequencies are at or below particle-particle Coulomb collision frequencies (see definitions at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268594/59023).

Answer (score 1):

Collective behavior in Plasmas is the phenomenon where the way the plasma as a whole reacts/behaves is dependent on the behavior of each and every particle in the plasma. The overall behavior is the sum of the individual particles' behavior.