# Mathematical form of distribution function with high energetic beam

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics

Maxwell Boltzmann distribution function (MBDF) has the form
$$f(v)=n(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT})^{\frac{3}{2}} exp(-\frac{mv^2}{2k_BT})$$ [Basic Space Plasma Physics by Rudolf A. Treumann & Wolfgang Baumjohann]. The shifted MBDF has the form $$f(v)=n(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT})^{\frac{3}{2}} exp(-\frac{m(v-v0)^2}{2k_BT}).$$

This is shown in the below figure for ms= 1.660539040 $10^{-27}$, kb=1.380 $10^{-23}$, T=100, v0=2000, wherein thick lines give the MBDF and dashed one gives the shifted MBDF.
[image: MBDF and shifted MBDF.].

As far as the beams in plasma are concerned, I believe that one should see a figure of the form:
[image: Beam DF]
Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

What is the mathematical expression that describes the above figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only plasmas where that *bump-on-tail* velocity distribution function (VDF) can exist are those that are either weakly collisional or collisionless, it is perfectly okay to add VDFs.  That is, those plasmas are neither in [thermodynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equilibrium) or [thermal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_equilibrium) equilibrium, so there is nothing wrong with adding two VDFs as they are not a single temperature (e.g., see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268594/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/375611/59023).

The general bi-Maxwellian VDF of species $s$ is given by:
$$
f_{s}\left( v_{\parallel}, v_{\perp} \right) = \frac{ n_{s} }{ \pi^{3/2} \ V_{T \parallel, s} \ V_{T \perp, s}^{2} } \ exp\left[ - \left( \frac{ v_{\parallel} - v_{o, \parallel, s} }{ V_{T \parallel, s} } \right)^{2} - \left( \frac{ v_{\perp} - v_{o, \perp, s} }{ V_{T \perp, s} } \right)^{2} \right] \tag{0}
$$
where $\parallel$($\perp$) refer to directions parallel(perpendicular) with respect to a quasi-static magnetic field, $\mathbf{B}_{o}$, $V_{T_{j, s}}$ is the $j^{th}$ thermal speed (actually the [most probable speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179057/59023)), $v_{o, j, s}$ is the $j^{th}$ component of the bulk drift velocity of the distribution (i.e., from the 1st velocity moment), and $n_{s}$ is the number density or zeroth velocity moment of species $s$.

Typically beams (i.e., the little bump in your merged VDF) are not isotropic, so it is common to have a VDF for the core and a VDF for the beam.  It is okay to use a form like Equation 0 for both, each with different densities and thermal speeds.  The non-equilibrium nature of the plasma allows two such VDFs to effectively stream past each other.  They tend to excite instabilities that lead to fluctuations like [Langmuir waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation).

You could get a little *fancier* and use a bi-kappa VDF.  The bi-kappa distribution function is given by:
$$
f_{s}\left( v_{\parallel}, v_{\perp} \right) = A_{s} \left[ 1 + \left( \frac{ v_{\parallel} - v_{o, \parallel, s} }{ \sqrt{ \kappa_{s} - 3/2 } \ \theta_{\parallel, s} } \right)^{2} + \left( \frac{ v_{\perp} - v_{o, \perp, s} }{ \sqrt{ \kappa - 3/2 } \ \theta_{\perp, s} } \right)^{2} \right]^{- \left( \kappa_{s} + 1 \right) } \tag{1}
$$
where the amplitude is given by:
$$
A_{s} = \left( \frac{ n_{s} \ \Gamma\left( \kappa_{s} + 1 \right) }{ \left( \pi \left( \kappa_{s} - 3/2 \right) \right)^{3/2} \ \theta_{\parallel, s} \ \theta_{\perp, s}^{2} \ \Gamma\left( \kappa_{s} - 1/2 \right) } \right) \tag{2}
$$
and where $\theta_{j, s}$ is the $j^{th}$ thermal speed (also the *most probable speed*), $\Gamma(x)$ is the [complete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html), and $\kappa_{s}$ is the kappa index and can be any value larger than 3/2.

Further we can show that the average temperature is just given by:
$$
T = \frac{ 1 }{ 3 } \left( T_{\parallel} + 2 \ T_{\perp} \right) \tag{3}
$$
if we assume a gyrotropic distribution (i.e., shows symmetry about $\mathbf{B}_{o}$ so that the two perpendicular components of a diagonalized pressure tensor are equal).

Comment: thanks for providing many insights. My query, again, is will Equation 0 will give the required plot? I tied with the above parameters, but I could regenerate the plot.

Comment: You need to sum two of them and then take a 1D cut because Equations 0 and 1 are 2D functions.

Comment: again, thanks for the tip. Now, I could regenerate the plot just by summing both equation which is given in my question. And I do not understand what is meant by 1D cut? Any thought about that?