# Is Wikipedia's definition of an ideal gas correct?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, definition, ideal-gas

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas):

> "An ideal gas is a theoretical gas composed of many randomly moving point particles that are not subject to interparticle interactions".

But suppose that two boxes of ideal gas at different temperatures are placed side by side and the separator septum is removed. In the end we will find a gas at an intermediate temperature so the molecules interacted. How does this agree with the definition given in Wikipedia?

Comment: You are completely right, if there is no interaction, then there can not be thermal equilibrium (in fact, in plasma physics 2 different species often take so long to reach full thermodynamic equilibrium, that they can be modelled with two different temperatures). More precisely: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/460468/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/375611/226902 (in this respect, your example of two gases mixing is not very different from the plasma case).

Comment: Most "ideal" physical systems have such degeneracies and most non-ideal ones can not be calculated at all. The ideal gas does, indeed, not satisfy the requirements of statistical mechanics because it is not ergodic. It is still a very useful approximation in many cases. A better definition might be something like "An ideal gas is the approximation of the behavior of a real gas in which interparticle interactions can be neglected for the purpose of the problem.". Yes, physics is sometimes like lawyering.

Comment: Speed of sound, diffusion and other phenomena directly involving molecular interaction could bring problems for the ideal gas model.

Comment: "But suppose that two boxes of ideal gas at different temperatures are placed side by side and the separator septum is removed. In the end we will find a gas at an intermediate temperature so the molecules interacted" - you're looking at this backwards. Ideal gas is a *model* (an abstract description of a real phenomenon that only focuses on certain aspects, and ignores others: that is, it's an *idealized* thing). You *can't* place to boxes of "ideal gas" side by side. You can place two boxes of *real gas* side by side, and a real gas has more complexity. 1/2

Comment: You can't look at a real experiment, see the outcome, and decide that that's what two containers of ideal gas will do under the same circumstances - that's fudging the model. You have to *compute* (predict) what the two ideal gases will do given the assumptions of the model, then compare with what actually happens in experiment. If it agrees, fine! If it doesn't - great - you just found an area where the model doesn't apply, at least not without modification (and are thus helping map out its domain of applicability) 2/2

Comment: A strongly idealized gas (point particles) explains the pressure on the walls but does not seem to explain the effect of the question (in reality I am not completely sure but the problem becomes unrealistic and uninteresting) but an ideal but less ideal gas (rigid spheres that collide elastically) explains it.  It all depends on what exactly we mean by ideal gas.

Answer (score 17):

The answer is written a few lines later: "The requirement of zero interaction can often be relaxed if, for example, the interaction is perfectly elastic or regarded as point-like collisions".

Answer (score 1):

The gas molecules can indirectly exchange energy through colliding with the box wall. Suppose a hot particle collides with the left wall of the box. This will make the particle transfer a slight leftwards momentum to the box and become colder, and then a cold particle colliding with the right wall of the box may gain a part of that momentum and become hotter.

Of course, if the box is rigid and infinitely heavy, this heat transfer mechanism doesn't exist, and you may indeed get a mixture of ideal gases with a non-Boltzmann velocity distribution, that never thermally equilibrates. But since almost no discussions on ideal gas thermodynamics assume that the box is infinitely heavy, there is no contradiction between most thought experiments on ideal gas thermodynamics with the definition of the ideal gas.

Comment: Speed of sound, diffusion and other phenomena directly involving molecular interaction could bring problems for the non-interacting ideal gas model, that is less useful outside of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal Gases are mostly used to study equilibriums or quasi-static processes. So even your very simple example would exceed its boundaries.